# getting empty body while sending post request using volley Android

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

When I am making POST request call using JsonObjectRequest in volley then on certain wifi it is sending empty body. But it works fine with StringRequest POST request. It is working fine on all mobile networks.

I am using node.js server and expressjs/body-parser. When I am making POST request using Postman, everything works fine.

What is the error? If anyone wants to see code I can provide.

POST request using StringRequest

```
  private void LoginUser(final String email,final String pass) {

        try {

            /*Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", email);
            params.put("password", pass);
            JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject(params);*/

            final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            try
                            {
                                Log.i("Inside try", "yes");
                                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("user");
                                Log.i("User name",jsonResponse.getString("name"));
                                Constants.setClinicName(jsonResponse.getString("name"));

                                String TokenDB=new JSONObject(response).getString("token");

                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),TokenDB,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                if(pd.isShowing())
                                {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                }



                                //Maintaining LogIn data till user clicks LogOut
                                SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("Token",TokenDB);
                                //editor.putString("username", username);
                                editor.commit();

                                //Printing Token in Log in case of null token debugging
                                /*String status=manager.getPreferences(ClinicLogin.this,"token");
                                Log.d("token", status);
*/
                                Intent intent=new Intent(ClinicLogin.this,MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }catch (JSONException ks)
                            {
                                ks.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Oops! The Username & Password Do Not Match. Please try again!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            //   Handle Error
                            if(pd.isShowing()) {pd.dismiss();}
                            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                                //TODO
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User not authorized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                                //TODO
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                //TODO
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                                //TODO
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error consuming request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else error.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("username", email);
                    params.put("password", pass);
                    return params;
                }

            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    7000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

POST call using JsonobjectRequest

```
private void LoginUser(String email,String pass) {

        try {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", email);
            params.put("password", pass);
            JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject(params);
            JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, jsonParams,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                // Parsing json object response
                                // response will be a json object
                                String TokenDB = response.getString("token");
                                JSONObject user=response.getJSONObject("user");
                                Constants.setClinicName(user.getString("name"));

                                //Constants.setTokenDB(TokenDB);
                                if(pd.isShowing())
                                {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                }

                                //Maintaining LogIn data till user clicks LogOut
                                SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("Token",TokenDB);
                                //editor.putString("username", username);
                                editor.commit();

                                //Printing Token in Log in case of null token debugging
                                /*String status=manager.getPreferences(ClinicLogin.this,"token");
                                Log.d("token", status);
*/
                                Intent intent=new Intent(ClinicLogin.this,MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Oops! The Username & Password Do Not Match. Please try again!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              }

                    }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            //   Handle Error
                            if(pd.isShowing()) {pd.dismiss();}
                            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                                //TODO
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User not authorized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                                //TODO
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                //TODO
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                                //TODO
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error consuming request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else error.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    7000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            requestQueue.add(postRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Paste what you have done till now. `certain wifi it is sending empty body?` 
Is your port is getting blocked by the WIFI?. Is it not a secured connection?

Comment: I have added the code. I am using volley library to make network request. How will I check port is blocked or not?

Comment: Are you receiving the request in the server? 
In server side for every request if the content length greater than zero then add some header to the response and check it in volley response.
Are you using http(80) for your request?

Comment: You are able to get body from postman manually?

Comment: Yes,  receiving the request on the server side with empty body. Yes I am getting response if the content length is greater than zero. How to check port no in volley? I think default port no is 80. we are using nginx server.

Comment: yes, @VishalPatoliyaツ

Comment: you given Internet Permission in manifest ?

Comment: Yes @VishalPatoliyaツ

Comment: you tried to print response in log ??

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.mwakidoshi;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Sly on 2017-11-17.
 */

public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {
    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params, Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = responseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params, Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: use that us a custome request class